# Should I use signed char for characters with negative values if I target portability?

Tags: c++, char, unsigned-char

A `char` data type is not guaranteed to be signed, which means on some implementations it is `signed`, and on others it is `unsigned`.  So why do people always ignore the `signed` qualifier?

```
char c = 'C'; // can be signed or unsigned
signed char sc = 'D'; // explicitly signed
unsigned char uc = 'e'; // explicitly unsigned
```

- For portability, should I always qualify a `char` with `signed` if I want the character to hold negative values?
- As I've learned other types like `int`, `long`, `short` are always `signed` unless explicitly qualified with `unsigned`.

Comment: signedness of `char` shouldn't matter unless you're abusing that type.

Comment: if you need a 1 byte integer, use `int8_t` or `uint8_t`. Don't use plain char for calculations.

Comment: Can you give us an actual example rather than just saying "if I want the character to hold negative values"? Why would you want that exactly?

Answer (score 5):

The type `char` is primarily intended to be used to store characters (or, in Unicode era, parts of character codes). In this sense, you should not care whether it is signed or not, as long as it is able to represent characters.

When you need `char`-sized integers, you should use `signed char` or `unsigned char` or one of their typical aliases (e.g. `int8_t` or `uint8_t`). This will ensure signedness and distinguish the types from characters.

Comment: What will happen if we try to assign an `int` value to a `char` like storing the return value from the Un-formatted Input Operation `std::cin.peek()` or `std::cin.get()`?

Comment: Or the ever popular character conversion functions [like `std::tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower#Notes)

Comment: @Maestro A typical integral conversion (http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.integral) will happen, to either signed or unsigned `char`. It is possible that signed overflow will also happen, if `char` is signed and the `int` value does not fit in its range.

Comment: @AndreySemashev: Then that will cause an implementation-defined behavior doesn't it?

Comment: @Maestro As of C++20, this will result in a truncated value (see the link from my previous comment). Before C++20, the result is implementation-defined.

Comment: OK Thanks for the link too.

Comment: "*When you need `char`-sized integers, you should use `signed char` or `unsigned char`*" - um, no, you shouldn't use `char` at all when you need integers. "*or one of their typical aliases (e.g. `int8_t` or `uint8_t`)*" - yes, do this instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: You mean I should use int8_t, uint8_t` for char-sized integers in some integral calculations?

Comment: @Maestro:  Use `int` or `unsigned int` when making math calculations.  These types are usually the size of the processor's register (and the compiler usually optimizes for this).  The only time you need to use `int8_t` or `uint8_t` is when you need or are limited to an 8-bit quantity (like in embedded systems and maybe cryptography).

Comment: One of the issues not to use 8-bit values for math is that processors are optimized for larger word sizes (like 32 or 64-bits) and the 8-bit values are very restictive, only 256 combinations or range.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews When to use or not to use `char`-sized integers is out of scope of this answer. But I'll say that there may be valid reasons to use types smaller than `int` for calculus or storage. For example, you may want to enforce the range of values or leverage unsigned overflow or save storage space when you know the value will always fit.